# Get PDF content from browser via Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

**Background**: 
I am trying to migrate a traditional web application into Windows 8 Store App with the least efforts, the basic idea is run the web application into the web view.

**Problem**:
1. The web app will produce a PDF file and display it directly in the browser using PDF binary (Base64), is it possible to listen the action, and intercept it, and so that i can get the PDF content?
2. If it's impossible to intercept the action (open PDF in a popup browser tab), is it possible to get the PDF content via Javascript in a existent rendered browser page (with PDF rendered)?
3. I previously thought that it's PDF viewer plugin helps browser to open PDF, but sounds not, as i checked my IE setting, there's no PDF reader plugin enabled, then how it can open PDF?
4. In the existing web application, the PDF page is invoked via "window.open(url,...), while the URL is the link to response PDF binary, the corresponding server side implementation of this link is very sample, it just "write" the PDF binary into the "response" object, and set the "content type" with "application/pdf", that's it.

Comment: I checked the source of the page that show PDF in browser, i found it uses tag "embed" to specify the source of the PDF. may i know if it's aligned in all the browser? If yes, then i have solution to get the PDF content (or at least its source URL) via Javascript.